# How can I use a table in more than one ado.net entity data model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship between the AspNetUsers and Bands, with BandAssigns as a bridging table.  So I created Bands.edmx and this all works great.  However, I then decided to create Venues.edmx for another many-to-many relationship, this time between AspNetUsers and Venues, with VenueAssigns as a bridging table.  However, when I created this, the AspNetUsers table disappeared from Bands.edmx

Is it not possible to have a table in more than entity data model? And if not, how do I get around this problem?

Comment: Yes it is (by renaming the generated class), but you shouldn't create separate contexts for each association.

Comment: I agree with Gert, it doesn't sound right to have two separate contexts here; however if you *really* do need to have two separate contexts (bearing in mind that AspNetUsers in Context A is a totally separate and different type than the one in Context B), then Code-First is probably a better approach anyway, since you have much more control over the classes.

Comment: How do you mean? If I use code-first, will it affect the database as it stands? I don't want to accidentally lose the data.